# What's the best func signature for a function that fetches an object and might not find it?

Tags: function, go, design-patterns, null

This is a very similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970974/what-function-signature-should-i-use-to-return-a-reference-to-an-object-that-mig), but focusing Go implementation.

Let's say you have a function that fetches an object using some ID. The function might not find that object.

Something like:

```
func FindUserByID(id int) *User {
    ....
}
```

How should you handle a situation where the user is not found?

There's a number of patterns and solutions to follow. Some are common, some are favorable in specific languages.

I need to choose a solution that is suitable in Go (golang), and so I want to go through all the options and get some feedback on what's the best approach here.

Go have some limitations and some features that can be helpful with this issue.

#### Option 1:

The obvious solution is to have the "Find" function return nil, in case the object wasn't found. As many know, returning nil is unfavorable and forces the caller do check for nil, making "nil" the magic value for "not found".

```
func FindUserByID(id int) *User {
    ...
    if /*user not found*/ {
       return nil
    }
    ...
}
```

It works. And it's simple.

#### Option 2:

Returning an exception - "NotFound".
Goland does not support exceptions. The only alternative is to have the function to return an error, and check the error in the caller code:

```
func FindUserByID(id int) (*User, error) {
    ...
    return errors.New("NotFound")
}

func Foo() {
    User, err := FindUserByID(123)
    if err.Error() == "NotFound" {
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Since Go does not support exceptions, the above is a code smell, relying on error string.

#### Option 3:

Separate to 2 different functions: one will check if the object exists, and the other will return it.

```
func FindUserByID(id int) *User {
   ....
}

func IsExist(id int) bool {
   ...
}
```

The problem with it is:

1. Checking if the object exists in many cases means also fetching it. So we pay penalty for doing the same operation twice (assume no caching available).
2. The call to "IsExist" can return true, but "Find" can fail if the object was removed by the time it was called. In high concurrency applications it can happen very often. Which again forces checking nil value from "Find".

#### Option 4:

Change the name of "Find" to suggest it may return nil. This is common in .Net and the name can be "TryFindByID".
But many people hate this pattern and I haven't seen it anywhere else. And anyhow it's still makes the nil value the magic "not exist" mark.

#### Option 5:

In some languages (java, c++) there's the "Optional" pattern. This makes a clear signature and helps the caller understand she needs to call "isEmpty()" first.
Unfortunately this is not available in Go. There are some projects in github (like https://github.com/markphelps/optional) but since Go is limited and does not support returning generic types without casting, it means another compilation step is required to creat an Optional struct for out object, and use that in the function signature.

```
func FindUserByID(id int) OptionalUser {
   ....
}

func Foo() {
    optionalUser := FindUserByID(123)
    if optionalUser.IsEmpty() {
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But it depends on 3rd parties and adds compilation complexity. It doubles the amount of structs that follow this pattern.

#### Option 6:

Go support returning multiple values in a function. So the "Find" function can also return a bool value if the object exists.

```
func FindUserByID(id int) (*User, bool) {
    ...
    if /*user not found*/ {
       return nil, false
    }
    ...
}
```

This seems to be a favorable approach in Go. For example, casting in Go also returns a bool value saying if the operation was successful.

I wonder what's the best approach and to get some feedback on the above options.

Edited: Changed the User to be pointer (better serves the example)

Comment: You forgot the Option which returns a `*User`.

Comment: "Goland does not support exceptions." -- How does your IDE figure into this discussion at all?

Comment: "Since Go does not support exceptions, the above is a code smell, relying on error string." -- Go does support exceptions. They're called "panic." Gut you're right, they should not be used for this. Beyond that, you don't need to rely on the error string, you can use an error type. This is what most of the stdlib does in situations like this.

Comment: Best depends on actual cases. If user is loaded from a database, that may result in an `error`, and so `FindUser()` should also return an `error`. If `FindUser()` finds user in memory which cannot fail like a database operation, then returning `User, bool` might be reasonable. If a user being non-existent is not an "error", e.g. you auto-create them in they don't exist, and checking / creating cannot fail (e.g. in-memory only), returning `nil` pointer could make sense.

Comment: Splitting the function into 2 usually breaks atomicity. There is no guarantee that a check for existence is valid by the time you go ahead to query it or create it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is fundamentally opinion-based, and as such I hesitate to answer. But there's enough going on here that I think it warrants an answer, not just comments.

You've given 6 options, but really there are only three. Most of your 6 options fall under my first category. At the bottom, I'll give a specific critique of each of your proposals.

1. Return the user, and a boolean indicating whether it was found.

   In this case, my preference is to always return a literal boolean (but emphasis: this is my opinion, not an objective fact):

   ```
   func FindUserByID(id string) (*User, bool)
   ```

   Of your 6 options, this is the most obvious to any casual reader of the code. It leaves no guesswork about whether a nil value might be returned, or if you have to look up some complex API to do a 2-phase lookup, etc.
2. Return the user, and an error, possibly including a 'Not Found' status.

   If you have the option of other error states (such as timeouts, database errors, malformed input, etc), then a simple boolean is not sufficient, and you *must* return an error (or panic, more on that in a moment).  In such a case, my preference (again: my opinion), is to use the error to convey not-found as well:

   ```
   func FindUserByID(id string) (*User, error)
   ```

   In this case, you can use a [sentinel error value](https://dave.cheney.net/tag/errors) that is easy to check from your caller:

   ```
   var ErrNotFound = errors.New("not found")

   func FindUserByID(id string) (*User, error) {
       /* couldn't find the user, so... */
       return nil, ErrNotFound
   }
   ```

   and elsewhere in your code...

   ```
   user, err := database.FindUserByID("1234")
   if err == database.ErrNotFound {
       /* behave accordingly */
   }
   ```

   Generally speaking, though, sentinel errors are not best practice. It's usually better convey the error type through an interface, but this is beyond the scope of this question. [Further reading here if you're interested](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully).
3. Return the user, or panic.

   And the final option is to panic (i.e. "throw an exception" in other languages). But this should be avoided in practically all cases, and it's absolutely the wrong approach for this sort of function. I just mention it here for completeness. **DON'T DO THIS**

   ```
   func FindUserByID(id string) *User {
       /* Couldn't find the user so... */
       panic("Can't find the user!")
   }
   ```

---

Here's my specific critique of your 6 options (again: my opinion).

- **Option 1:** Return nil when not found.

  This is non-intuitive. My advice is to only do this when the zero-value (`nil` in your case) is valid in its own right. It probably isn't for a user. It might be for something like a count.
- **Option 2:** Return an exception

  Your example actually only returns an error, not an exception (panic). Returning an error is a perfectly valid option, but *do not* resort to checking error strings. See my discussion above.
- **Option 3:** One function to check, one to retrieve

  This is non-intuitive, and racy. It's not obvious how to use this cumbersome API, so I would avoid it. It's also racy, because there's no guarantee that between the check and the retrieve, that a new user hasn't been created, or an existing one deleted.
- **Option 4:** Change the name to suggest it returns nil

  This would be a slight improvement over option #1, but not idiomatic Go. There are better alternatives.
- **Option 5:** IsEmpty() method

  This is just a cumbersome way to return a boolean. Prefer an actual boolean.
- **Option 6:** Return a boolean

  This is a valid option, seen throughout the standard library. It's appropriate if no other error condition is possible. See above commentary.